Не обновляются стили на github pages
Заливала на гитхаб проект, все отображалось прекрасно, но в один момент на gh pages перестали обновляться стили (для наглядности поменяла в медиа 480px .nav {background-color: orangered;}), хотя в style.css обновления есть...
Вот ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/Yana16/Window_Help

У вас страницы собираются из ветки gh-pages https://github.com/Yana16/Window_Help/tree/gh-pages

Спасибо огромное!!! Все поняла)))
